# Location coordinates does not change when using LocationListener

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am using LocationListener on my application. However, whenever my location changes or onLocationChanged(Location location) method is executed, the coordinates of my location does not change at all. I am riding inside a car and had traveled several meters to kilometers already without my location changing. What could be the problem?

My code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
{LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener()
{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        //location.getLatitude(), location.getLongtitude()
        //location coordinates does not change at all everytime onLocationChanged is called even after I already move several meters or kilometers.
    }

    //...
}
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: Are you using the reuiqred permissions? When are you removing the lcation updates listener?

Comment: Yes. I am using the required permissions. I'm not removing the update listener because I always need to check the user's location. Do I have to remove and then add it again every time it's called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, 
        locationListener);
```

You might be using the network provider. The listener is normally removed in the activty onPause. And you can set the listener in the onResume event of the activity.

Im not sure what is the logic behind finding the best provider by android. But GPS is always considered to be the most accurate compared to the network provider. But there are conditions when getting a location lock by the GPS is not possible. Thats when the network provider comes into use.

I normally create a simple class that calls a function to get location coords. Inside the function, I first request the location using GPS. I wait for 30 seconds for the location, if it is not received, then I request it using the network provider. This way I can always ensure that I am getting the GPS value as my first preference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! After further investigating, I found out that my phone is using the network provider even though I set my application to use the best provider. My GPS is also on at that time so I never suspected that my phone will use the network provider. Is there a way to always determine the best provider of the network and then set it as the provider for location manager once it changes? It seems to me that once I set my provider, the value sticks until the end of the activity. Thanks also for the tip on removing the activity onPause and setting it again onResume.

Comment: Are you using a thread or AsyncTask to continuously call that method?

Comment: Both are ok. But I normally use a thread and handler approach.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your location is changing but you are overlooking the decimal part of latitude and longitude. Note the last digits of the decimal part before and after location change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way in your code

```
if(isInternetEnabled==true)//check for internet connection here
{
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,  
        locationListener);  
}
else
{
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,  
        locationListener);  
}
```

Because it happens with me that `GPS_PROVIDER` doesn't give quick response to location update then `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

Comment: Thanks! But GPS does not depend on the internet connection right?

Comment: Yes. I know that there are many ways to determine the location. However, if I will determine my provider based on if I have internet access or not, then it will still not guarantee if that provider is available. It is possible that I have internet access but I don't have GPS.